# Error HH700: Artifact for contract "@uniswap/lib/contracts/Babyl............." not found

Tags: solidity, uniswap, hardhat, react

I'm using [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) to compile solidity contracts.
In the contracts I'm importing Uniswap's contracts SDK to use them. But when I run

```
yarn hardhat compile
```

in terminal it says

```
Error HH700: Artifact for contract "@uniswap/lib/contracts/libraries/Babylonian.sol:Babylonian" not found. 

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH700 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Here is how I imported Uniswap

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import '@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol';

contract THE_CONTRACT {
  string public name = "SOME PROPERTY";
```

and here is hardhat config

```
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import { INFURA } from "./src/config";

const config = {
  solidity: "0.6.6",
  paths: {
    artifacts: "./src/artifects",
  },
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      chainID: 5,
      url: INFURA,
      accounts: [
        "0xTHEACCOUNT",
      ],
      timeout: 60000,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 1,
    },
    evmVersion: "byzantium",
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. have you tried installing npm i @uniswap/v2-periphery? or in your case "yarn add"?
2. do you have compiler version 0.6.6 in your hardhat config?
3. try to remove `cache` and `artifects` folder and compile the contracts again

Might be one of these things...

Comment: Yes I have both of them

Comment: I added the config in the question

Comment: It all started when I deleted the compiled contract and compiled them again if that helps

Comment: Okay, few more things than:
1. Try deleting your artifacts and cache folder and compile again.

Comment: On my end, i cannot reproduce the error. Not sure if maybe you misspelled naming somewhere?

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: I got a similar problem when deleting `artifacts/` folder while forgetting to delete `cache/` folder. Jut needed to delete it all again